# Java InputStream / XSL Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading, xslt

I have some code that was originally purposed for single threaded processing that is now being utilized by multiple threads. I encountered strange xsl parsing errors on an xsl that has been unmodified and usually works fine.

I don't seek code correction, I'll be refactoring this class for thread safety through my own research. Tips on this are welcome but not necessary for an answer.
**I seek an explanation of what probably / could have happened to produce the strange errors seen below**.

E.g. Thread A entered line of code X, stopped at line Y, thread B entered line X, read stream S, stopped. Thread A now performs Z to stream S and corrupted it... etc. My vague hunch is that the object 'xsl' somehow got corrupted when 2 threads manipulated/read it at once, but I lack knowledge of how InputStream objects and Source objects work inside the api.

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  ... 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Style sheet should be fine. Let me know if you think otherwise.

Error:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:33: The encoding declaration is required in the text declaration.
[Fatal Error] :1:2: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Couldn't create transformer object for xsl javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
```

These errors happened many times and persisted until an app restart. These clearly point to a bad xsl. But I did verify the file to be not corrupt.

Java code:

```
public class IntegrationRequest {

  private static Source xsl; // data that i believe got corrupted
  private static Transformer inputTransformer;
  private static JAXBContext createContext;

  ...

  // this public method is now executed by multiple threads at once
  public String getResponse()  {
    createTransformerInstance(); // err thrown in here
    String xmlRequest = getXmlRequestString();
    String response = executeRequest(createHttpConnection(), xmlRequest);
    return response;
  }

  private static Transformer createTransformerInstance() {
    if (inputTransformer == null) {
        TransformerFactory factory =  TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            inputTransformer = factory.newTransformer(getXSLTemplate("/Integration_Request.xsl"));
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            if (log.isErrorEnabled()) {
                log.error("Couldn't create transformer object for xsl ", e);
            }
        }
    }
    return inputTransformer;
  }

  private static Source getXSLTemplate(String fileName) {
    if (xsl == null) {
        InputStream xslInputStream = IntegrationRequest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        xsl = new StreamSource(xslInputStream);
    }
    return xsl;
  }

}
```

Note how getXSLTemplate caches xsl - the app will keep that bad data until restart. This is the basis of my theory that it got corrupted by multiple threads on first load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors show that parsing of the stylesheet has failed - the XML parser did not see valid XML when reading the stylesheet document. This has most likely happened because two or more threads started to create the stylesheet, all using the same `InputStream` in the `xsl` variable. A possible scenario is:

- Thread 1 calls `getResponse` for the first time, `xsl` is created, thread 1 starts reading from `xsl`.
- Thread 2 calls `getResponse`, also doesn't see a non-null `transformer`, starts reading from the same `xsl`, corrupting the parse process in thread 1.

Note that `Transformer` also is not a thread-safe class. You should use a `javax.xml.transform.Templates` instead and create a `Transformer` from the `Templates` for each transformation.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines but my only reservation to that hypothetical situation is that when `xsl` is instantiated, `InputStream xslInputStream` is a local, unshared variable - thought the second thread would simply save the uncorrupt xsl into memory once again.

Comment: @jiman the second threads sees a non-null `xsl` variable and then starts consuming from the same `InputStream` (which is stored in `xsl`) as the first thread. Add log statements to the code to verify this hypothesis.

Comment: I dug into the StreamSource class on the api and your comment makes a lot more sense now. One thread could have a stored input stream and begin parsing, yield to another thread who overwrites that input stream, who then yields to the original thread who resumes parsing boom - corruption. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to get a detailed explanation of exactly what happened.

You have static variables that are being reused when multiple threads use the class, and those threads will step all over each other.  This must be refactored so that each thread can have its own instance of your class, with all variable being instance variables.  The details of how to accomplish the best refactoring depend on information you haven't provided.

This falls under the umbrella of "undefined behavior", which includes everything from continuing to work correctly, through exceptions, corrupted data (likely), the JVM crashing (unlikely), or the CPU throwing off a shower of sparks like in the movies (dramatic, but really unlikely).

Comment: Agreed and understood regarding not getting a detailed explanation - moreso wanted to see if my theory of that `xsl` object got corrupted when 2 threads tried to instantiate and read it at the same time was at least plausible and not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

A StreamSource is consumed by use: in general, you can't use it more than once. (This is one of the design faults in JAXP: some kinds of Source are consumed by use, and others aren't, and the documentation doesn't make this clear.) So caching the StreamSource is not an appropriate thing to do. The thing you should cache is the JAXP `Templates` object, which represents a compiled stylesheet. Apart from anything else, there's a lot of work in creating a Templates object from a StreamSource, and you don't want to repeat this work. The Templates object is guaranteed thread-safe.

Comment: That provides great insight into what happened here. Thread1 and Thread2 enter the meat of `createTransformerInstance`, regardless of whether or not xsl got corrupted, the first thread to process it consumes the stream, leaving the second to error out, thereby leaving `inputTransformer` as null and `xsl` consumed. All subsequent attempts to use `xsl` try to use a consumed source and also error out.